# Spawn blocks at random locations

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I'm trying to create elements in random locations on the screen but I have run into some trouble. Creating the elements works but when I try to make them have random locations, nothing happens. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here's my code:

```js
var newObject = document.createElement("DIV");
newObject.setAttribute("class", "object");
newObject.setAttribute("id", "powerup");
document.body.appendChild(newObject);
var powerup = document.getElementById("powerup");
var object = document.getElementsByClassName("object");
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
  object[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 50 + "px";
  object[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 50 + "px";
}

function createObject() {
  var newObject = document.createElement("DIV");
  newObject.setAttribute("class", "object");
  newObject.setAttribute("id", "powerup");
  document.body.appendChild(newObject);
  for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    object[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 50 + "px";
    object[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 50 + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#powerup {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="createObject()">Create a Block</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [made a CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLoBve) with your code.

For those elements to have their `top` and `left` properties have an effect, you need to add `position: absolute;` to the `#powerup` elements.

```
#powerup {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but your JavaScript code is selecting a new random location for each pre-existing `#powerup` element whenever you click the button.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working correctly. Its able to set top and left of each `#powerup` element. The only problem is that the `position` of `#powerup` is `static` by default. So you just need to change css of `#powerup` element to

```
#powerup {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

`position: absolute` can also be used. Choose the one that fits your requirements.